# Symfony functional tests give infinity loops after upgrading to 2.2

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony-2.1, functional-testing, symfony-2.2

I've encountered problem after upgrading my Symfony from 2.1 to 2.2. 
When runing all functional tests at once (notice this isn't happening when single tests are being run, no matter which) I get an error with infinity loop stucked at

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '150' reached, aborting! in project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader.php on line 81
```

Part of trace:

```
...
14. Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->submit() project_path\other_path\Tests\Controller\LoginControllerTest.php:53
15. Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client.php:224
16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client.php:264
17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client.php:111
18. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client.php:61
19. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() project_path\app\bootstrap.php.cache:411
20. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() project_path\app\bootstrap.php.cache:1101
21. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() project_path\app\bootstrap.php.cache:975
22. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() project_path\app\bootstrap.php.cache:990
23. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:135
24. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:167
25. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:53
26. call_user_func() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:164
27. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:164
28. call_user_func() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:447
29. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:447
30. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener->handle() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall.php:66
31. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener->onSuccess() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:143
32. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:0
33. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader->findFile() project_path\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader.php:95
...
```

Before I've upgraded all tests worked fine, now they throw that error when using:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form();
$form['_password'] = '123ASDasd';
$form['_username'] = 'MattKing';
$crawler = $client->submit($form); //this is LoginControllerTest.php:53 from error above
```

or

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Matt King')->link();
$client->click($link); // --> error
```

or

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->followRedirects(true);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login'); // --> error
```

Another problem was while using default symfony translations functions. After switching user's locale - test threw same error as above. When I commented out switching locale, then the others error (like the one above) occured. Notice it might have been caused by same issues as above.

I've searched for reason for few days and gave up. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you using the FOSUserBundle or is this your own login implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I've resolved this by adding this to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

XDebug should not run on your production server, thus it should not throw an error.

(See [this issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/238))

Comment: I fixed this issue with using the same above :-)